# in Cypress i can not make the command 'promt' to work

Tags: cypress, prompt

I am doing API testing with Cypress and I want to have a prompt that asks for a value.
I use a function to try to get the value.

The commands: **Alert** and **Confirm** shows a popup windows, but **Prompt**  (or window.prompt) does not work (nothing shows/no error message)

How can I get the Prompt to work?

**My tests are:**

**Image:**

[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

///
describe('Example to demonstrate handling of JavaScript Alerts, Confirm, Prompt in Cypress', () => {
console.clear()

```
   it('get answer ', () => {
    var answer = window.confirm("Would like to confirm?");
    if (answer) {
      console.log('YES')
    }
    else {
      console.log('NO')
    }
  });

  it('get answer ', () => {
    var name = alert("Your name is Null");
      console.log(name)
  });

  it('get answer ', () => {
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    console.log("Hi " + name)
  });
})
```

Comment: Can you add the Cypress code that you've tried?

Comment: kod is already in the question:
API.read.js  call  defMiljo.js

Comment: Right, but I'm not seeing any Cypress-related code, and that was what I was asking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.